# Calling static Java methods from rhino javascript

Tags: java, javascript, methods, rhino

I have static java methods which I add to javascript with this method:

```
public void addJavaMethod(Method method)
{
    try
    {
            FunctionObject fo = new FunctionObject(method.getName(), method, m_scope);
            FunctionObject.putProperty(m_scope, method.getName(), fo);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I always use the object class for parameters in these methods because it otherwise comes up with errors, for example:

instead of

```
static void setSomeFloatValueHere(float value){}
```

I use:

```
static void setSomeFloatValueHere(Object value)
{//convert this object to a float}
```

With booleans I can do a direct cast:

```
static void setBoolean(Object b){someBooleanObject = (Boolean)b;}
```

But with int,float,long,double, etc, I cannot do this.
I receive an error:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

How can I get this to work with those types as well? and possibly other non primitive type objects?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is probably not an Integer, but rather *Number* which has an *intValue()*

You can check the actual type by using value.getClass().getName().

Comment: Thanks, you are right about wrong types for some things, like I found out there are only doubles, not floats. I'm stuck on long values though. In js, if i put: var x = 0; setLong(x); where setLong takes a long value, I checked the type in the way you wrote and am getting "org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined". 0 Shouldn't be undefined should it?

Also, I can use NativeJavaObject as a parameter instead of Object for other more complicated objects, and get the object value with NativeJavaObject.unwrap();

Comment: @user1177453 no floats?  Where?